# Eclipse incorrectly applying <!-- --> when commenting javascript code in html file

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse

I am using latest Eclipse 2019-09 with Generic Text Editor.
On my HTML I tried to comment out javascript fragment with `Command + /`. Instead of putting `//` I get `<!-- -->` which is fine for markup but not for Javascript.

Is there anyway to fix it ?

```html
<html>
<body>

<script>
<!--
function myFunction() {
...
}
-->

function myFunction2() {
...
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Eclipse 2019-09 has not yet been released. Which version do you use exactly (see _Eclipse > About Eclipse IDE_)?

Comment: Block comments are specified in _Window > Preferences: TextMate > Language Configuration_, but I don't know how to change it. So please [report the issue to Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper).

Comment: to be precise (I just downloaded it yesterday):
Version: 2019-09 M1 (4.13.0M1)
Build id: 20190718-1346

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually need this for my Svelte project, so I follow the steps:

- General > Content Types > Text > Wild Web Developer supported Web dev file > Add Child, fill File associations: *.svelte, Associated editors: Generic Text Editor
- General > Editors > File associations > Add, for file type *.svelte
- Download language-configuration.json and svelte.tmLanguage.json from https://github.com/UnwrittenFun/svelte-vscode/find/master into your workspace
- Preferences > TextMate > Grammar > New and select svelte.tmLanguage.json
- Preferences > TextMate > Language Configuration > New and select language-configuration.json select Svelte file for Content Types

Eclipse Version: 2019-09 M1 (4.13.0M1) Build id: 20190718-1346